# Sum of the sequence $A_n$ = $\frac{1}{2^n-1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have been trying to find the value of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n-1}$,
But I dont really know how so I've tried a few things and managed to express it (maybe unusefully) as $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{nm}}$

Comment: It seems that there is no analytical formula for the sum. Or perhaps you need to use some special functions.

Comment: Check Wolfram alpha. It seems there is no "nice" closed form. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5B1%2F%282%5En+-1%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2CInfinity%7D%5D